# Understanding the implementation of Space vector algorithm in C

Tags: c, embedded

Looking at the following formulas and the instructions to compute them. I tried to understand where the factors 2,  262144 and 131072 came from but didn't understand. The simplified equation for the sector 5 is T/2 + (Y - Z)/2. But in the instruction I can see that it is T/4 + (Y - Z)/2 * 131072 for TimePhA for example.
I think they store the variables in a 32 bit integer but limit the resolution to 2^17 or something like that. But what I dont understand is why PWMPeriod/4 instead of PWMPeriod/2 given the simplify formula TimePhA = T/2 + (T/2 + Y - Z)/2 = T/2 + (Y - Z)/2.

And for TimePhB it's just TimePhA + Z. If they mapped the result in a 16 bit fixed point it would be TimePhA + Z/65536 but in their implementation its TimePhB + Z/131072  (which is 2*65536).

My third procupation concerning the first formula. It's stated that Ualpha = T*sqrt(3)*Valpha and Ubeta = -T*Vbeta but they implements it as Ualpha = sqrt(3)*Valpha and Vbeta = PWMPeriod*Vbeta*2. I dont understand the logic either here

Can someone explain me how they end up with that please ?

```c
    int32_t wX;
    int32_t wY;
    int32_t wZ;
    int32_t wUAlpha;
    int32_t wUBeta;
    int32_t wTimePhA;
    int32_t wTimePhB;
    int32_t wTimePhC;

    wUAlpha = Valfa_beta.alpha * (int32_t)pHandle->hT_Sqrt3;
    wUBeta = -(Valfa_beta.beta * ((int32_t)pHandle->PWMperiod)) * 2;

    wX = wUBeta;
    wY = (wUBeta + wUAlpha) / 2;
    wZ = (wUBeta - wUAlpha) / 2;

    /* Sector calculation from wX, wY, wZ */
    if (wY < 0)
    {
      if (wZ < 0)
      {
        pHandle->Sector = SECTOR_5;
        wTimePhA = (((int32_t)pHandle->PWMperiod) / 4) + ((wY - wZ) / (int32_t)262144);
        wTimePhB = wTimePhA + (wZ / 131072);
        wTimePhC = wTimePhA - (wY / 131072) ;

        pHandle->lowDuty = (uint16_t)wTimePhC;
        pHandle->midDuty = (uint16_t)wTimePhA;
        pHandle->highDuty = (uint16_t)wTimePhB;
      }
```

I want a clear explanation of the computation process.

Formula image 1:

[image: formulas image 1]

Formula image 2:

[image: formulas image 2]

Comment: I'm guessing that some of these variables are [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) with a factor of 131072. So multiplication/division is needed when converting between them a a regular integer.

Comment: Looks like fixed point math. Those factors are both a power of two.

Comment: ... so shifts might have been clearer than divisions, but the implementation-definedness of right-shifting negative numbers might constitute good reason to avoid that, whether in general or for the specific machines the code targets.

Comment: While the code is suggestive of fixed-point representations, a conclusive answer relies on specifications of the meanings of the variables that is not presented in the text, including the linked image. So there is insufficient information in this question to answer it definitively. If the source material specifies how the values are represented, that needs to be in the question. If it does not, it is defective.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes it's fixed point math. I think they store the variables in a 32 bit integer but limit the resolution to 2^17 or something like that. But what I dont understand is why T/4 instead of T/2 given the simplify formula TimePhA = T/2 + (T/2 + Y - Z)/2 = T/2 + (Y - Z)/2

Comment: @interjay why 131072 ? and why PWMPeriod/4 instead of T/2 given the simplify formula TimePhA = T/2 + (T/2 + Y - Z)/2 = T/2 + (Y - Z)/2 ?

Comment: You'd have to ask whoever wrote this, there's no way for us to know.

Comment: In the implementation 2 is replaced with 2 x 2^16, which suggests Q16 fixed point.  The specific questions you have added in comments should be in the question.